# Provider's name with slash will make error

Tags: pact

when I make a 'put request' to add pact-file like this

```
$c->request('PUT', "http://localhost:8000/pacts/provider/someString/someProviderName"  . '/consumer/someConsumerName' . '/version/0.0.1',
            [
                'body' => $str,
                'headers'=>['Content-Type' => 'application/json']
            ]);
```

the name of provider is "someString **/** someProviderName" 
this request will 404

if I change the "someString/someProviderName" to "someString-someProviderName"

it will work rightly(201 Status Code)

> my english is poor T-T，sorry~~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a slash in the provider name here, as it will request a different resource on the server (hence the 404).

My suggestion is to remove the slash, or to URLEncode the provider name itself.

Comment: Oh thanks!Now I change '/' to '_', because URLEncode will cause '%7B', I think its a little ugly.

Comment: Why do you need a slash?

Comment: The number of providers is equal to the number of interfaces, so I want to generate name of provider from url path.

Comment: Is there a problem with my understanding of the provider?

Comment: Yeah might be worth having a chat at slack.pact.io, it seems unusual